# How to build a list of tags from classes in a hierarchy

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

There's a logger that uses "tags" and some other dotted-namespace-things to divvy up events. My program implements logic across various classes, most of which are inherited, but some are mixins.

How can I cleanly have the various levels of inheritance build up a list of items available to the final object, including multiple-inheritance/mixins? Overloading everything and calling the subclass thing kinda works (except for mixins), but is a bit verbose (and would be even more verbose if I did some crazy MRO stuff)

```
class Base(object):
    def tags(self):
        return ['project-base']

class DoThinger(Base):
    def tags(self):
        return super(DoThinger, self).tags() + ['thinger']

class SpecialThinger(DoThinger):
    def tags(self):
        # OK, if verbose
        return super(SpecialThinger, self).tags() + ['special-1']

class SprinklesMixin(object):
    def tags(self):
        return ['sprinkles']

class SprinkleThinger(DoThinger, SprinklesMixin):
    def tags(self):
        # would need to do some magic MRO stuff
        return super(SprinkleThinger, self).tags() + ['specialsprinkles']

print(SpecialThinger().tags())  # -> ['project-base', 'thinger', 'special-1']
print(SprinkleThinger().tags()) # -> ['project-base', 'thinger', 'specialsprinkles']
#                                          (missing 'sprinkles' ^)
```

Ideally I'd like to do something like the below so I'm not constantly repeating logic, but I'm not sure what goes in `...`.

```
class Base(object):
    _tags = ['project-base']

    def tags(self):
        ... # something...
        return []

class DoThinger(Base):
    _tags = ['thinger']

class SpecialThinger(DoThinger):
    _tags = ['special-1']

class SprinklesMixin(object):
    _tags = ['sprinkles']

class SprinkleThinger(DoThinger, SprinklesMixin):
    _tags = ['specialsprinkles']

assert set(SpecialThinger().tags()) == {'project-base', 'thinger', 'special-1'}
assert set(SprinkleThinger().tags()) == {'project-base', 'thinger', 'sprinkles', 'specialsprinkles'}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the "typical" use case for metaclasses. The normal class creation process in Python uses the "type" metaclass: it is responsible for creating the correct  `__mro__` attribute which enables multiple inheritance. By extending the metaclass behavior we can make the `_tags` attribute to be extended on class creation time, using the `__mro__`:

```
class MetaBase(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        new_tags = set()
        for ancestor in cls.__mro__:
            new_tags.update(getattr(ancestor, "_tags", set()))
        cls.tags = new_tags

class Base(metaclasMetaBase):
    _tags = ['project-base']


# In Python 2.x, the class declaration is like:
class Base(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaBase
```

Another option is to have the metaclass hold a descriptor for `_tags` in the classes, computing each class' tags_  at the time it is requested. It should wok, but could have severe side-effects. Like, instances of those classes may not "see" the attribute - just when it is request through the class itself:

```
class MetaBase(type):
    @property
    def tags(cls):
        a = set()
        for supercls in cls.__mro__:
            a.update(getattr(supercls, "_tags", set()))
        return a
```

Comment: Could I move the `tags` property/method to the base class and do `for ancestor in self.__class__.__mro__: ...`? Is there some side-effect to that vs. using the metaclass?

Comment: The problem of using that as a property on the class, is that it would only work as such if retrieved from an instance of each class. If you try `Base.tags` you'd get the "property object" not your updated tags set.

Comment: It is possible to use the property in the metaclass as above  and combine it with a `__getattr__`   method on the Base class that would allow `tags` to work both on the Classes and on their instances.